# How to check field from database with jquery and show check or cross?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a page and I ask them zipcode. While they are filling the form right after they finish writing 5 numbers of zipcode, It will check if it is covered from my database and will show a check or cross sign near it and will disable submit.

To summarize.

1. Will wait for visitor to type 5 digits zip code( If we can check if customer only enters number it will be a plus and great)
2. It will check if it is covered in database ( I don't ask for php part. Probably we will send it as POST to a php file)
3. If it exists in database it will show check else it will show cross and will not allow the form to be submitted.

I checked some websites but couldn't find an exact solution.

Thank you

Comment: There are some questions that I found answer myself. I hadn't accepted them since I thought it is not fair. But if this is the rule now I accepted all. Thanks.

Comment: You can always vote up an answer, but I think it is not logically correct if you accept an answer that is not acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need have an image tag besides the zip code text box with the `src` attribute set to an invisible image. Then perform an ajax upon the `blur` event.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="zip" name="zip">&nbsp;<img id="imgconf" src="images/blank.png">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#zip').blur(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "script.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: "zip=" + $('#zip').val(),
     dataType: "text",
     success: function (data){
         if (data=="1"){
            $('#imgconf').attr("src", "images/correct.png");
         } else {
            $('#imgconf').attr("src", "images/wrong.png");
         }
       }
     });
});
```

For the numeric validation, you may use the same PHP script to return another flag besides "1" and display it in another span element that the data entered is not numeric. Just add another key-value pair in the data part, maybe.

Comment: This seems nice. But How can I restrict the user to press submit button if the zip is not covered?

Comment: $('#formid').submit method. Return false if it's not covered. Sorry for not doing it for you--from reading, I believe you'll learn more being pointed in the right direction, yet having to figure it out.

Comment: You can always declare a global Javascript variable and flag it inside the `if (data=="1")` condition. Then upon form submission, check that variable if it has been flagged as true, 1 or whatever you can think of, and proceed submitting the form. You can also add an `$('#submit').attr('disable',true);` inside it in order to allow or prohibit the user from clicking the submit button.

Comment: @ZaldyBaguinon: I tried and uploaded here. http://jsfiddle.net/kvEkr/ . The problem is when I write zip code, it doesn't check real time. I check after I click somewhere else in the page. Also, It doesn't check when when I write 5 digit zip code. This is my simple php script.php code http://codepad.org/6RGMJjYn

Comment: @SNare: You may put the function inside a setTimeout() function to check for a specific time interval. You may also put it in a keyup or keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AJAX. JQuery has a built in AJAX function. On each keyup event, you can have it run this AJAX function. The PHP should return a value of either 1 or 0 to make it easy. 1 obviously is match, and 0 is no-match.

```
$('#YourObjectID').keyup(function (event) {
    searchZips();
})

function searchZips()
{

    var myJSON = $.ajax({
        url: options.script + '?Q=' + curValue,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (msg) {
            if(msg==="1"){
                // CODE TO SHOW YOUR X DIV
            }
        }

}
```

You will want to also add functionality on clearing the search, checking if null or empty string, etc., etc., but this is the basics that should get you going. I use this all the time. Once you get the hang of it, it's VERY useful. Then look into building a jQuery plugin. Once you can do the above functionality, you can build it into a plugin (with tons of cool options!) GOOD LUCK and happy programming.